# Cannot Update Windows 7 Clients to Windows 10 via WSUS (except ONE!)

Tags: wsus, windows-10

We are trying to upgrade our Windows 7 clients to Windows 10 via WSUS.
Only one Windows 7 client is recognizing the Windows 10 1607 upgrade as applicable. All the rest show "Not Applicable" or, less frequently "Unknown". There is no difference between the client that is recognizing the update and those which are not that I can discern.

Things I have tried/checked so far:

- I think I have all the requisite WSUS updates needed to service
  windows 10 via WSUS.
- I have also tried adding the MIME type.
- Existing Windows 10 clients are updating fine Windows Update is configured via GPO to allow Upgrades across the board.

Is there any advice on what I can look at to get these clients to recognize the update?

Comment: Yeh it sounded like you are expecting a snarky response. People are actually quite nice round here - don't presume the worst! I will submit an edit...

Comment: @Daniel Fair, but try also not to blame the user for the problem with no evidence. It could have been his coworker, or the guy who quit last month, or an anonymous Microsoft developer who caused the problem.